# Task.Factory And Process.Parallel

Tags: task-parallel-library

**Question :**  Some class is having M method and M method  is  calling M1 and M2 method logic through Task.Factory.

**M Method Logic Code:**

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessAndSendResultAsync(ConfigKey, content));

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessProcessorsInParalle(ConfigKey, content));
```

**M1 Method Logic:** 
     M1 method has been invoked through taskfactory from M method and M1 method is having some prorocessing logic.

**M2 Method Logic:**
     M2 method has been invoked through taskfactory from M method and Somewhere Created Mulitple processors(in C# logic) and that processors getting invoked in parllel using parallel.foreach in m2 method.

```
Parallel.ForEach(processes, (p) =>
{
    p.Process(content, configkey);
});
```

How this logic can improved or does it have any performance impact?

Comment: please clarify your question

Comment: Clarification :M methods are having two method M1 and M2. Both methods have launched in thread using taskfactoy. M1 method is doing some business and send result to queue. I have created two differents businessprocessor and based on the request i want to run both businessprocessor in parallel. In M2 method, i have find out collection of  enabled processors and use Parallel.foreach to process each of business processor and send result to queue. Is this logic can be improved or Does it have any performance impact ?

Answer (score 0):

The thread pool thread executing `ProcessProcessorsInParalle` is blocked while performing the `Parallel.ForEach`, essentially wasting that thread. A small optimization would be to run each call to `Process` in a TPL task.

```cs
var processTasks = processes.Select(
  p => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => p.Process(content, configkey))).ToList();
```

If you need to perform further processing after the `Process` calls have finished, you can move the rest of `ProcessProcessorsInParalle` into a separate method and invoke it as continuation.

```cs
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(processTasks, t => FinishProcessInParallel());
```

That said, in general, you need to profile your application to know if it has performance problems.